# Amazon ECS task can't connect to Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy my application to aws using ECS (it's working on local, already build to docker image an pushed to ECR), I created a get started cluster then I choose custom with my image uri.

I already create a mysql database with VPC security groups which accept connection from anywhere to port 3306.

But when my task running, it always stop with this log:

```
2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:272)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:46)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at tech.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:118)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at tech.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at com.vpark.VparkApp.main(VparkApp.java:69)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)

2021-09-09T02:20:55.213+07:00   at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
```

I think because my application can't connect to RDS. what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly configured the ECS task with the RDS hostname?

Comment: @MarkB of course, it's `database-xx.culndou2fn7b.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com` with port 3306

Comment: Is the ECS service and RDS instance in the same region and VPC?

Comment: They are the same region but not same VPC

Comment: Why aren't you deploying them in the same VPC? You'll either need to setup VPC Peering, or make the database publicly accessible.

Comment: I already make database is public